# Numerical Differentiation of List in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I numerically differentiate a list in Mathematica *without* first fitting it to a mathematical expression (ie. using `FindFit`)?

Specifically, I would like to find the point of maximum slope in the list.

I have considered using `Differences` and finding the maximum difference, but noise in the data renders that inaccurate. Smoothing the data with `MovingAverage` does not help either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question here is how to estimate the derivative when your data is noisy.  Once we have a method for this, we can think about implementing it in Mathematica.  Google turns up e.g. this: 
http://math.lanl.gov/Research/Highlights/PDF/tvdiff.pdf

Comment: http://math.lanl.gov/Research/Publications/Docs/chartrand-2007-numerical.pdf

Answer (score 6):

You could try a `ListConvolve` with a Gaussian kernel to smooth your data. One of the nice features of this is that the *derivative* of the **convolution** with a Gaussian kernel is equivalent to *convolving* with a **derivative** of the Gaussian kernel.

Here is some sample data:

```
data = Table[Sin[x] + .5 RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi], .05}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

This is a simple convolution with a Gaussian kernel:

```
data2 = 
  Block[{\[Sigma] = 2}, 
   ListConvolve[
    Table[1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma]) E^(-x^2/(2 \[Sigma])), 
         {x, -2 , 2, 1/10}
    ], data, {11, 11}
   ]
  ];  
ListLinePlot[data2]
```

[image]

Convolution with the first derivative of a Gaussian:

```
data3 = 
  Block[{\[Sigma] = 1}, 
   ListConvolve[
    Table[-((E^(-(x^2/(2 \[Sigma]))) x)/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma]^2)), 
      {x, -2 \[Sigma],2 \[Sigma], \[Sigma]/10}
    ], data, {11, 11}
   ]
  ];
ListLinePlot[data3]
```

[image]

You may want to play with the sigma parameter to see what gets optimal results in your case.

The whole theory behind this is called [Scale Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space). Note that the above statement about convolution holds for continuous space. [For a discrete implementation, the kernel could be chosen somewhat better.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation)

Note further that, just as MovingAverage, a convolution can move the features of your data.

Comment: @belisarius Tell me where I forgot one